# Surveys on unknotting number

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Any knot diagram could be converted to an unknot by cross change.
The *unknotting number of a knot diagram* is the minimal number of cross changes needed.

A knot could have many different diagrams and hence the corresponding unknotting numbers (of knot diagram). Pick up the smallest one and define it as the *unknotting number of the knot*.

There are cases where the unknotting number (of a knot) is achieved on a knot diagram without minimal crossing number. In general, it is a difficult problem to compute the unknotting number.

> **Question.** Is there a good survey paper that collects the phenomena and typical tricks in this field?

Comment: I believe there are examples where the unknotting arc isn't part of any minimal-crossing diagram.  It's probably helpful to think of the unknotting arcs as embedded arcs in 3-space that connect the over/under crossing -- you are asking if these can be made to be vertical striaght-lines in a minimal planar diagram. Unfortunately I don't know these examples off-hand, but they typically appear in papers discussing unknotting number. i.e. from this perspective you can talk about unknotting arcs with respect to any diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Lackenby discussed the unknotting number (and mentions some explicit knots for which we do not know the unknotting number!) in

*Lackenby, Marc*, [**Elementary knot theory**](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/1604.03778), Woodhouse, N. M. J. (ed.), Lectures on geometry. Oxford: Oxford University Press (ISBN 978-0-19-878491-3/hbk). 29-64 (2017). [ZBL1393.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1393.57002).

There are numerous references and a general discussion. In the [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03778.pdf) of this paper, the section on the unknotting number begins on page 23.